# Stop page from reloading?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing an interactive webpage for an assignment. I have the required information in a database table, and clicking on different page elements queries the database and displays the relevant info for that particular selection. However, the page refreshes before the additional info is displayed. Is there a solution that enables the information to be queried from the database and displayed on the page, without refreshing the page?

For context, or in case my explanation wasn't good enough, here is my work in progress: (Sorry about the url)

*removed*

Thanks.

EDIT:, sorry- added code

```
    <?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
    {?>
        <tr id="tablerow" class="output" onclick="document.location.href=page.php?id=<?php echo $row['item_id'];?>'" style="cursor:pointer">
            <a href="elements.php?id=<?php echo $row['item_id'];?>">
            <td><?php echo $row['field1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['field2']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['field3'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['field4']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['field5']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['field6']; ?></td>
            </a>
        </tr>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('id_val').style.background="#d3d3d3";
        </script>
    <?php }
    ?>
```

Comment: the usually approach for this would be to use AJAX

Comment: You need to post the code that you have questions about here, so that in the future people can look at the question and know what it was about. It cannot be about a changing website.

Comment: To avoid page reload, you will need AJAX, or to build a list of all of your outputs on page load and switch through them with JavaScript

Comment: You can avoid ajax by just targeting an iframe that will contain the results.

Comment: As mentioned in pieces of other suggestions, use an iframe, use AJAX, or have the page refresh via a link click, and use GET or URL parameters to pass the element into the url, and query the database after.

Comment: I tried your link. I didn't find any information about abusing your nipples.

Comment: @Homer6 : lol.. What not to choose as a domain name while creating an academic website...:)

Comment: @user2752988 If you're still having troubles with this, email me and I'll help you: hidemynipples@hmamail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an use case such as this, I'd highly recommend using meteor.com.

I've used PHP/MySQL for years and meteor for about a year as well. Something like this takes a lot less time with meteor (and, my opinion, the learning curve isn't as steep as raw AJAX).

Of course, I'm sure other people will have their opinions too.

My two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Because You are using links. Use jquery page loader: http://api.jquerymobile.com/loader/